# Magento : Hide Payment Method Based On Product to Cart

Tags: magento-1.9, onepage-checkout, payment-methods

I want to hide offline payment method, if some particular product is added to cart. 
For those special products payment should be online, So I need to hide all the offline payment method in that case.

How can I hide payment method based on condition?

Comment: payment methods that are used to received payment after delivery. Like COD, Cheque etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At last I have found the way to **hide all Offline payment methods based on product in cart** Please follow the below step:

Step1 :  Create a "Yes/No" product attribute with code "is_offline_payment_available" and assigned to the attribute set. This attribute is used to define that the
"Offline" payment option is available or not. If it is set "Yes" "Offline" available else not available;

Step2 : Create an observer in app\code\local\YourPackage\YourModule\etc\config.xml with the below code.

```
<frontend>
    <events>
     <payment_method_is_active>
            <observers>
                <yourmodule>
                    <type>singleton</type>
                    <class>YourPackage_YourModule_Model_Observer</class>
                    <method>hideOfflinePayment</method>
                </yourmodule>
            </observers>
        </payment_method_is_active>
      </events>
</frontend>
```

Step3 :Create the observer class and method in app\code\local\YourPackage\YourModule\Model\Observer.php with the following code.

```
<?php

class YourPackage_YourModule_Model_Observer
{

  public function hideOfflinePayment($observer){
    $instance = $observer->getMethodInstance();
    $result = $observer->getResult();
    $allPaymentMethods = $config = Mage::getConfig()->getNode('default/payment')->asArray();
    $allOfflinePayments=array();
    foreach($allPaymentMethods as $code=>$value) {
        if($value['group']=='offline'){
          $allOfflinePayments[]=$code;
        }
    }
    if (in_array($instance->getCode(), $allOfflinePayments)) {
            $cart = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();
            $flag=1;
            foreach ($cart->getAllItems() as $item) {
                $_product=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($item->getProductId());
                if($_product->getIsOfflinePaymentAvailable()!=1){
                    $flag=0;
                    break;
                }
            }
            if($flag==1){
                $result->isAvailable = true;
            }
            else{
               $result->isAvailable = false;
            }
    }
  }

}
```

Comment: You can accept your own answer, too ;)

Answer (score 2):

+1. Just an improvement to your answer ....

```
$cart = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote();
```

Can be replaced ...

```
$cart = $observer->getQuote();
```

And for performance ...

```
$_product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($item->getProductId());
```

**Should** be replaced with ...

```
$_product = $item->getProduct();
```

You have to add this to your `etc/config.xml` to access your custom attribute in quote item

```
<global>
   ...
    <sales>
        <quote>
            <item>
                <product_attributes>
                    <is_offline_payment_available/>
                </product_attributes>
            </item>
        </quote>
    </sales>
   ...
</global>
```

Comment: Good work @sv3n